# Using PHP printf to produce sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, printf

I tried to produce a query with `printf` to be executed on MySQL:

```
$query = printf("INSERT INTO author VALUES (null,'%s','%s','%s',null,null,null,null,null)", 
    $command['pseudonym'],$command['name'],$command['surname']);
$result = $connection->query($query);
```

But the result is this weird error:

```
INSERT INTO author VALUES (null,'pseudo','nome','cognome',null,null,null,null,null)
Database access failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '83' at line 1
```

The produced query perfectly wors in PhpMyadmin. 
I tried also a version of the code without `printf` and it works:

```
$pseudo = $command['pseudonym'];
$name = $command['name'];
$surname = $command['surname'];
$query = "INSERT INTO author VALUES (null,'$pseudo','$name','$surname',null,null,null,null,null)";
```

What's wrong with the version using `printf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `sprintf` since you want to store the query string for later use.

Comment: O my God! This is so embarrassing. I'm using PHP since few days so I was not aware of the two versions printf and sprintf :S

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). PDO has named parameters (look [here](http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.prepare.php)) that does what you need (plus it takes care of escaping and sanitization)

Comment: I'm using PHP since few days and I studied it on a very basic book: Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS & HTML5 3rd Edition By Robin Nixon. It did not mention about PDO. I will definitely take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `printf()` use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO author VALUES (null,'%s','%s','%s',null,null,null,null,null)", 
    $command['pseudonym'],$command['name'],$command['surname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

sprintf is used here because

sprintf has all the formatting capabilities of the original printf which means you can do much more than just inserting variable values in strings.

For instance, specify number format (hex, decimal, octal), number of decimals, padding and more. Google for printf and you'll find plenty of examples. The wikipedia article on printf should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't "null" have to be '' to be seen as an empty value in the database?

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO author VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','','','','','')", 
$command['pseudonym'],$command['name'],$command['surname']);
```

can be wrong ofcourse...